# webserver not starting in opscenter

Tags: http, opscenter

I have a compiled-to-rpm opscenter package that dumps the files to /opt/mypckage

everything is okay when I execute /opt/mypackage/opscenter/bin/opscenter -f it will turn up the opscenter web which includes http.log on the log directory

I have created a start-script which is tested from tarball

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "exec 'sudo /etc/init.d/opscenterd start'"
exec sudo /etc/init.d/opscenterd start
```

wierd thing is- yes it will start the opscenter service using the script above but the url is not running using port 8888 and no http.log generated. is there any way I can tweak this on?

The opscenterd.log

```
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Log opened.
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: twistd 10.2.0 (/usr/bin/python2.6 2.6.6) starting up.
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: set uid/gid 9093/9094
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Logging level set to 'info'
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: OpsCenter version: 5.2.4
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Compatible agent version: 5.2.4
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Cluster config dir './conf/clusters' does not exist yet
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: No clusters are configured yet, checking to see if a config migration is needed
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Cluster config dir './conf/clusters' does not exist yet
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: No clusters are configured
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Authentication disabled
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Starting webserver with ssl disabled.
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Stats Reporter is connected via HTTP
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: SSL disabled
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  WARN: Unable to import SSL, further definition actions will fail.
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Starting Definition Update Service
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  WARN: Python may not have been compiled with SSL support, disabling cloud provisioning (No module named Ec2Launcher)
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer starting on 8888
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer instance at 0x1dbf758>
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 []  INFO: Unhandled error in Deferred:
       2016-06-21 02:13:32+0800 [] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 317, in startApplication

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/app.py", line 653, in startApplication

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/service.py", line 277, in startService

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1141, in unwindGenerator

    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks

      File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/OpsCenterdService.py", line 55, in startService

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/service.py", line 277, in startService

      File "/opt/msp/pkgmypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/internet.py", line 110, in startService

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/internet.py", line 131, in _getPort

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 419, in listenTCP

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 867, in startListening

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 45, in doStart

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/web/http.py", line 1755, in startFactory

      File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/Logging.py", line 72, in _openLogFile

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 162, in __init__

      File "/opt/mypakage/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 34, in __init__

    exceptions.AssertionError:
```

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/opscenter.log` (or `/opt/mypackage/log/opscenter.log` if it logs there...)? What about your `/etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf` (or `/opt/mypackage/conf/opscenterd.conf` if it's there)? Is the interface and port configured as expected in that config file?

Comment: hi Thomas, that is what I'm not seeing on etc/opsenterd and conf/opscenter.conf, I'm not seeing any of how to check httpd for port 8888

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/opscConfigProps_r.html

The port entry in the [webserver] section lets you set the port. There are also log settings in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the opscenter`s permission to write logs.

Try allowing opscenter to actually write his logs defined in opscenter.conf

That means assign ownership of /var/log/opscenter to opscenter user.

```
chown -R opscenter:opscenter /var/log/opscenter
```

Restart the opscenterd service, tail the opscenter.log to see how the service launches.

Load it in your browser, enjoy.